# How to delete all rows(data) from sqlite database while starting the activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I have created the Simple Application of the sqlite database. In which i am successful to implement the insert data. But i want to delete all the data while starting of the activity.
I have use the cursor to fetch the data and display. But dont know how to delete all the data.
I have use this.db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null); to delete the all rows. but it will not delete my data that are added before in database.
I have implement the Database Example from this link: [Here is the Link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/0/page/1)

So, Please let me know, what i have to do, to delete all the data while starting the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think in the starting of the activity firstly u need to check whether the cursor.getcount() > 0 then fire delete query.

hope may work for u...

Comment: hehehe...yup jema aapde sara hoie eno ans apay

Comment: I think you both are from India. Anyway Thanks for the help. Let me try it. I am also from India.

Comment: yes.....we are indians and were collegues :) anyways does that solution work for u ?

Comment: will you please give me the delete query ?

Comment: Ok Thanks. let me try. Still i am not able to delete all data. And after deleting that data if i again insert that then it will inserted after the last index.

Comment: If i want to display all the data by cursor then what should i have to do ??

Comment: @Richa : I want to display all the data by cursor then what should i have to do ?